# How to remove ETAG header on play framework 2.1.1? (i'll use akamai)

Tags: http, netty, playframework-2.1, etag

I'll set akamai in front of my server, so i need to remove ETAG header from my responses.

Please, anyone could tell me the easy way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to remove ETags?

Comment: I need to remove the Etag in 2.3.7 -> how did you end up loving this?

Answer (score 0):

In `application.conf`:

```
http.useETag=false
```

I have only seen this associated to older versions of Play, so I cannot tell it is still available.

Comment: I think that is not available, as i've tried and still having ETAGs, just change cache-control, not remove ETAG. Any help?